# How to stop accessing the user from specific URL scheme

Tags: php, .htaccess

I was working on a Project & I added 404 Page not Found code in htaccess file of it.

This 404 Error Code working fine for all type of urls if someone accidentally type the wrong name of page etc.

But, I try to add the same name of page 2 times in the URL path and it show me something very strange.

Lets suppose i have a website `http://example.com`

It has a page named dashboard.php, So I first try to access it using `http://example.com/dashboard.php`. It show me the dashboard.php as normally it should be show me.

**Issue:**

When I try to access this dashboard.php using `http://example.com/dashboard.php/dashboard.php`, It show me all the texual content without including css,js,images files.

**Screenshots:**

`http://example.com/dashboard.php`

[image: View]

`http://example.com/dashboard.php/dashboard.php`

[image: View]

My htaccess code (Working fine):

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your error page, use only absolute links (with domain, or from root with `/` in the beginning), especially for css or images.

Or you can add in the header:

```
<base href="http://example.com/">
```

or

```
<base href="/">
```

You can stop the user from accessing url like this with htaccess :

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html

Comment: +1 for Good Suggestion.

But, Can you tell me how can I stop the user from accessing like this URL ?

Like http://example.com/index.php should not access using http://example.com/index.php/index.php

Comment: I added the parameter in my solution